# Logo Critique - Personal Brand

Tags: logo, critique

[image: Andi SChwartz Logo]

So I'm updating my portfolio and feel like I have some nice work to show, but what kind of designer doesn't have their own brand, right? I sat down with pen and paper, drew some sketches. Then replicated on the computer. My thoughts... my name is Andi... I also hunt and compete in archery and I wanted to reflect that somehow without being too literal (the "D" makes a bow)... the arrow also shows forward direction, movement. I tried making a two color logo, but wasn't liking it. I love deep red, but could really adopt any color palette with this mark. I like it also white in a reverse. My concerns...

**Does the point of the arrow look like I used clip art?**

I created it with the same degree angles as the "N" as well as thickness.

**Is it okay that the arrow makes it feel a little unbalanced?**

**Maybe the angle and point of the "A/N" help that?**

I tried making the arrow come out the left side, but I felt it took away from the arrow and the "N" making the "A".

Comment: I would mimic the curve of the D for the left side of the arrow.... or I'd at least explore that. It may be helpful for you to review our [Critique Guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work). As this question stands, answers would be purely opinion-based and not a great fit for the site.

Comment: Hi Andi, thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. As Scott suggests, please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks! If you have other questions, give the [help] a read or ping one of us in [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: The space between the logo and your name is veeeeery slightly less than the space between your name and "graphic designer".  I know it's probably a trivial thing, but I noticed it right away.

Comment: I think the mark is trying too hard. How about paring doing the concept a bit? A bow an arrow can be a nice mark in and of itself. Maybe strip down that mark down to the more basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

I know its off topic, but have you thought about using the words 'graphic design' and dropping the 'er'- just thinking it would allow you to expand your brand, employees etc

Comment: I apologise for leaving this as an answer instead of a comment! Stupid iOS App lol

Comment: Ooh, there's an app?! I just found this awesome site, I'll have to get that!

Comment: Yeah, it's just called stack exchange - pretty handy, but I just figured out you can't delete answers on it haha

Answer (score 0):

Personally? I like it without the art.

Your name, what you do (without the er). Clean and perfect keming. Bold red on a linen business card? (no raised lettering PLEASE) That'd be all kinds of wow. The only thing I'd suggest in that respect is to try about +5% kerning between letters. Solid, clear, professional.

If you're going to have the art tho, the arrow should be a bit higher angle. On a card, it would be small enough that the angle would appear shallower and it may just come off looking like an error.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your comment! I posted on another site and someone complained that the arrow shouldn't be angled at all because that's not realistic. I am an archer, I know that. But again, I didn't want it to be immediately obvious either. I too am drawn to just my name, bold and solid. I personally have a dislike of linen paper, but I get what you're getting at! Thank you!